# Slow Startup of SQL Reporting Services 2008 in Native Mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are experiencing a slow start up time on the first report request of the day, or when there have been no report requests for an unknown period of time.  In SQL Reporting Server 2005 installations we would set up the App Pool to avoid recycling the Reporting Services applications.

However, my client installed SQL Reporting Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 in Native mode.  There is no IIS installation that I can locate.  I've checked through the SQL Reporting Service Configuration Settings, the Help files and forums and have not located a solution for this problem on a Native installation.

How can I control the recycling of the Reporting Services application when installed in Native mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did not find the parameter referenced in tcc'sresponse.  However his response did clue me in to the existence of configuration file; I did find a page that had detail on the contents:

[MSDN: How to: Modify a Reporting Services Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630448.aspx)

In it I found the RecycleTime parameter.  It defaults to 720 which feels like the 20 minutes or so it took to time out.  I set it to 28800.

I restarted the Reporting Services service for good measure, and accessed the site.  It took the usual minute or two to come up and during that time the server was working hard.  It is snappy now; I will test throughout the day to see if this keeps Report Services from recycling the process and rebuilding every 20 minutes and report back to this site.

Comment: The parameter is in minutes. 28800 = 480 hours!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. This also helps (I needed both) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784918/asmx-web-service-slow-first-request/784947#784947

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  @matt is 480 hours a bad thing??? are there bugs(memory leaks) in SSRS that require it to be shutdown every 12 hours?

Comment: This helped me too. I'm curious about whether there's a Microsoft Connect issue logged for this.

Comment: Also, I believe that if you set the RecycleTime to zero it should no longer sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is to add a ProcessTimeout key in the rsreportserver.config file.  There is this key in this file from the default installation but it is commented out.  I'm not sure if this is minutes or seconds, but I modifed it to 28800 and the process was still running first thing this morning after no activity for over 12 hours.  The first report loaded in a few seconds.

The file is located in ~/program files/microsoft sql server/msrs10.mssqlserver/reporting services/reportserver

I also modified the 7200 in this file.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server 2008` does not use IIS, which is why the RecycleTime parameter moved to the RS config file. This also means that you can install the report server on your database server for better performance, without also having to install IIS.

The default RecycleTime of 720 (12 hours) should be reasonable for a report server that is only active during regular business hours. Nevertheless I have the same issue, even though I schedule a report subscription to run at 7:30 AM every weekday to cause the report server to initialize for the day.

I am wondering now if the RecycleTime parameter really is specified in minutes or if this might be a documentation error. I am going to try a larger value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2, and there are two settings (which were initally commented-out) in my *rsreportserver.config* that I uncommented and configured. My values are shown below:

```xml
<Add Key="ProcessTimeout" Value="4320" /><!-- seconds -->
<Add Key="ProcessTimeoutGcExtension" Value="30" /><!-- seconds -->
```

At the time of this writing, these config elements [are not documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in the MSDN docs for the *rsreportserver.config* file for SQL Server 2008 R2, however there is a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955811) that briefly describes them under *More Information*:

> There are two configuration settings that determine how long the
>   Process Monitor waits for service activity before stopping the
>   service. These settings are defined as follows:
>
> 1. **ProcessTimeout**
>      This
>      setting applies to any operation that Reporting Services is
>      performing.
> 2. **ProcessTimeoutGcExtension**
>      This setting applies only if
>      garbage collection is in progress, and the ProcessTimeout value was
>      reached.

Using the `ProcessTimeout` setting kept my SSRS instance awake, and setting the `RecycleTime` setting to a suitably large value (in my case 30 days, or 43,200 seconds) helped stave off the mandatory recycle that is incurred when that time span elapses.

Answer (score 0):

By setting RecycleTime to 28800 you are only increasing the time between slow startups. It will still take time for the first report to run after the 480 hours. You can set RecyleTime to 0 to stop it recycling if this helps.

If this is not an option you can keep it alive by a number of methods such as:
1.) Scheduling a dummy report in SSRS Report Manager Web site (My favoured approach)
2.) [Scheduled Script](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/07/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/)

I realise this is an old question but it's not well documented, hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: I tried your first approach but it doesn't work. Indeed the snapshots were being generated regularly but when I made a request to reporting service url, it took a while to be loaded.