# Can i configure a .net Web Service to prevent asleep?

Tags: .net, web-services, configuration, sleep

The first time you call a Web Service Methods the web service wake up and takes a long time to respond. After that the web service responds almost instantaneously, but if there is not a call a while the web service back to sleep again and take a while to wake up again.

- Is some way to prevent Web Service asleep?
- how long takes the web service sleep if there is no call? If there is no way to prevent asleep, i thougth make a service that calls to a dummy method every some minutes to prevent this behavior

Thx very much!

Comment: A web service never goes to sleep. It is always listening on the port. Sounds like you are selecting data from a database? If you are the problem is that the database keeps data in the cache and then after a while flushes the cache. We need a little more information here.

Comment: Finally i've found a post with same problem: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784918/asmx-web-service-slow-first-request . There is some tips to try solve it.